# Ember Simple Auth different redirects after authentication

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I'm using [Ember simple auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) in my app and it's working great, but I've run into a scenario that I'm having trouble getting around.

The library lets you specify the route to redirect to after a successful authentication by overriding `routeAfterAuthentication: 'index'`. This is working fine, however, I'm finding myself in a situation where I want to have two different types of redirects. When a user first logs in, I want them to go to `/dashboard`, but when they first sign up and authenticate, I want them to go `/settings`.

I was hoping to be able to do something like this after successfully creating an account, but it's still trying to use the `routeAfterAuthentication` option for the transition:

```
var _this = this;

this.set('identification', _this.get('email'));
this.set('password', password);

this.send('authenticate', function() {
  _this.transitionToRoute('settings');
}, function() {});
```

Is there a way to specify which route to transition to after authenticating on one-off basis? Maybe there's a better way to log someone after they create an account without needing to go through the `authenticate()` method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply override the `sessionAuthenticated` [method in the application route](http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/ApplicationRouteMixin.html#method_sessionAuthenticated) and implement your own logic. Beware though that the default implementation will not always transition to `routeAfterAuthentication`-- if there's a previously intercepted transition stored in the session, `sessionAuthenticated` will retry that instead.

Comment: marcoow, this event is not triggered when session is restored, right?

Comment: @marcoow Is it possible that this is no longer possible in Simple Auth 1.0.1?

Comment: @Apex `sessionAuthenticationSucceeded` is no longer correct. Instead, override the `sessionAuthenticated` method-- I've updated marcoow's answer to match these names.